# sqlite android replace char

Tags: android, sqlite

i want so replace a char(160) with char (20) in a ORDER BY statement, but

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(column,CHAR(160),CHAR(20))
```

Throws an Exeption because CHAR() ist unknown. How can i cast a ascii code in SQLITE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(column, CAST(X'A0' AS TEXT), CAST(X'14' AS TEXT))
```

`A0` and `14` are in hexadecimal format